# regex lookaround is adding width

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I had the following regular expression:

`\/.*?(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*+\/[gimy]*`

Which is supposed to match regular expressions, unfortunately I found out that this regex is matching this line of code too:

```
var a = b / c; // comment
```

Because of having the division symbol `/` and the comment `//`.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rL9vV6/1) says that it's matching `/ c; /`

So what I tried to do is add this negative lookahead like this:

`\/.*?(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*+\/[gimy]*(?!\/)`

I intended to exclude those matches that has the `/` character after them.

**It didn't work!**

And while testing it in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dA4lN4/2) I see that it's actually adding a width and matching `/ c; //`

So I end up adapting with this width that has been added and writing my expression like this:

`\/.*?(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*+\/[gimy]*(?!\/| |[a-z]|[A-Z])`

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/iW4xJ7/2)

However, I don't feel that this is the right thing to do!

So is there anyway that I can exclude those matched that has the `/` character after them?

https://regex101.com/r/jR6vQ2/1

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php ? What is it you're trying to do? Match regular expressions in source code?

Comment: @Mardoxx I found a bug on php-based JS minification library. and I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: I've added regex101 links please see them

Comment: Hard to know what you want.. Something as simple as `\/(.*)\/[gimy]` works fine for your test case.

Answer (score 0):

### Update #1

Your problem is, while engine is taking steps to the last but one `/` it sees another `/` which should not be there (negative lookahead), so it backtracks and give up one character (now it's exactly before `//`) it does some backtracks again as you have some more patterns. finally it expands matching by `.*?` to one character and matches the last `/` now it's satisfied since `(?!\/)` is accepted.

In this case you should tell engine to fail and not continue backtracking by calling an atomic group:

```
(?>/.+?/)(?!/)[gimy]*
```

Modified regex to include escaped slashes:

```
(?m)/(?!/)[^/\\\n]*(?:\\.[^\n/\\]*)*/(?:[gmiy]+|\s|$)
```

Explanation:

```
 /                        # regex starting delimiter
 (?! / )                  # no `/` after
 [^/\\\n]*                # negated character class including `/` `\` `\n` (zero or more times)
 (?: \\ . [^\n/\\]* )*    # an escaped character followed by any character excluding a new-line and `\` (zero or more times)
 /                        # regex ending delimiter
 (?: [gmiy]+ | \s | $ )   # match any of these
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE4xI9/3)